# php session tracking cookies (multiple session handling on same domain)

Tags: php, domain, session, cookie

I have 2 applications, both have password based login, database,etc., the passwords are different, databases are different, applications present are in different folders.

1. Log into the first application at `example.com/abcd`. Username: admin, Password: admin
2. Then you can open this second application at `example.com/abcd1`. Even though the passwords are different, databases are different, applications present in different folders still the second application is not asking for login. It directly goes to the index.php. page.
3. If we logout from the second application, we will get logged out from the 1st application as well.

Have tried running the below, scripts :

-> under httpd.conf [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QiRSXEvp)
-> under .htaccess which didnt exist so created one  and added  **SetEnv session.use_cookies='0';**

Either throws out a error.

Comment: though risky is it impossible to set a multiple session handling of same domain narrowed the path? btw thanks for the link

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890360/how-can-i-manage-separate-session-states-for-two-different-websites-on-the-same